# Free API for converting entire app to different language

Tags: flutter, dart, localization

I am looking for a free API similar to Google Translate that I can integrate into my Flutter app to convert the entire app to a new language.

I am thinking about maybe converting from English to Spanish or Portuguese.

So, all of the text on the screens will be in the language of choice and all of the data coming from the db will be converted on the screen.

What APIs are you using for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you [**this**](https://github.com/delay/getx_google_sheets_translation_code_generator) tutorial.
You can use Google Sheets to generate translations for multiple languages and can import directly into your project.

According to the tutorial, you need to use [getx](https://pub.dev/packages/get) for localization[multi languages].

**It's totally free**

Answer (score 0):

For free translation, you check this library [Libretranslate](https://libretranslate.com/)